# Opencart check the vqmod version installed

Tags: php, opencart

Is there any way to check the version of vqmod which is installed from within the extension of opencart?

I am having far too many users send me support emails and the majority of the time its because they need to upgrade vqmod. I want to add a warning message saying they need to upgrade vqmod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vQmod's version number is private and only there for the purposes of letting a user know the version. I guess you could load the file and use a regex to find the version number. My concern is just what you're using that is incompatible. vQmod is backward compatible right back to 1.0 from the latest version. The simplest answer is to make it clear on your extension that version X is required or later of vQmod for your extension to be compatible. I sell over 40 mods, the majority of which are vQmodded in some way or another and I've not come across this with my customers

Comment: I thinks its because I try to write my whole extension to be backwards compatible with the different opencart versions. So I had a few issues with file not existing and the vqmod not skipping the skip when it has `<file name="catalog/model/account/customer_group.php" error="skip">`

Comment: I will try to find out more if it happens again (might just be a file caching issue)

Comment: I knew it, just come across this error again in vqmod 2.1.4, if the file does not exist and has error="skip" it will log/abort.

Comment: That feature wasn't added until 2.1.6 - http://code.google.com/p/vqmod/wiki/Changelog

Answer (score 10):

To check which version of VQMOD you are running open the file..
/vqmod/vqmod.php
look on line 7 for...
private $_vqversion = '2.3.2';

Comment: I meant how could I access this from within the PHP code, ie an extension being installed I wanted to confirm the user had the correct version installed.